# How do I get the Revolution Slider in the header on the homepage, but not the blog index page?

Tags: homepage, blog-page

I am trying to get a carousel slider from the [Revolution Slider Addon](https://revolution.themepunch.com/) into the header on the [homepage](https://www.90dayfluency.com/) only. And I want it under the header bar (where the menu is). However, the template I'm using doesn't inherently support the slider. So I decided to go into the header.php and input the code myself to put the slider over the top of the default header image. However, when I do this, it also puts the slider in the header on the [blogs post page](https://www.90dayfluency.com/blog). It doesn't appear anywhere else on the site besides the home (desired) and the blogs post page (undesired).

Is there a way to restrict this code to ONLY the website homepage and not appearing in the header anywhere else? Maybe some kind of if-conditional?

Here is the code section where I put the slider in header.php:

```
<!-- Mobile Menu -->
    </div>
    <div class="header-fix-wrapper">
        <header class="clearfix<?php if($sonus_opt['podcast-mode'] == 1){ if(!is_home()){ if(is_single()){ if($this_is_podcast == 1){echo " single-header";} }elseif(is_front_page()){echo " home-header"; }}} ?>">
            <div class="header-bar">
            <!-- Head Bar -->
            <?php add_revslider('funky-slider','homepage'); ?>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can conditionally display it only in front page by  `is_front_page()`

reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/

Try:

```
if (is_front_page()) {
    add_revslider('funky-slider','homepage');
};
```